# Changing Caller ID on IVR flow

Tags: twilio, ivr

I'm setting up a `IVR` flow on `Twilio` Flex using Studio, and I'm having some problems changing the `CalledID` for the **CONNECT CALL TO** widget.

I have a **SET VARIABLES** widget before the **CONNECT CALL TO**, with a single variable:

```
Key: Origin
Value: Sales
```

**On CONNECT CALL TO** widget, I changed `CALLER ID` to `{{widgets.set_variables.Origin}}`, but even so, the `caller id` on the destination phone is always the origin phone number, and not "Sales", as I want it to be.

Also, is it possible that when the person of the destination phone number answers, an audio is played before the call is transferred?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried checking the debugger? You're likely getting an invalid caller id error.

Comment: No error on the debugger...